# 【tasks.json】 How to get the path of the currently selected folder in the side bar in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

```json
"tasks": [
{
    "label": "Create_Folder_and_Markdown_File",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "touch \"${workspaceFolder}/${input:promptFolderName}/${input:promptFolderName}.md\"",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": true
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "Create_Folder"
    ]
},
{
    "label": "Create_Folder",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "mkdir \"${workspaceFolder}/${input:promptFolderName}\"",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": true
    },
}
],
"inputs": [
    {
        "type": "promptString",
        "id": "promptFolderName",
        "description": "Enter the folder name:"
    }
],
```

In VSCode, I want to develop a task to create a certain folder with the name I type in the prompt, and then create a markdown file of the same name inside the folder.

[image: dir]

Say I have selected **1** in the side bar. I want to create `1/mark`, and then create `1/mark/mark.md`. And I want to achieve this by **typing in the prompt only `mark`, with folder `1` selected in the side bar**

**However, I seem to have no access to the folder I SELECT IN THE SIDE BAR!!!**

`${fileDirname}` is not Valid because I do not open any file in the editor.

`${workspaceFolder}="1"` is also wrong because I do not want the root folder.

Comment: use the second icon, or use the context (right click) menu

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve. if you want to get something selected in the explorer, why are you using inputs?

Comment: I do not want to simply create a folder. I want to get ACCESS to the PATH of the selected folder in the tasks.json. And I want to do something fancier . :P

Comment: @starball, sorry for misleading over-simplification. I have updated my question~

Comment: related request for API: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3553 (not quite related, since it sounds like you want a variable or a command, but related in that if you wanted to write an extension to create that command, you wouldn't be able to I think)

Comment: awful... It's quite difficult for me, without experience of digging into vscode core, to customize some functions for myself.. @starball

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and with v1.56.0 you can implement this by using the context menu of the VSC File Explorer.

Define the following in your `tasks.json`:

```json
"tasks": [
{
    "label": "Create_Folder_and_Markdown_File",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "touch \"${input:getClipboard}/${input:rememberFolderName}/${input:rememberFolderName}.md\"",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": true
    },
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "dependsOn": [
        "Create_Folder"
    ]
},
{
    "label": "Create_Folder",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "mkdir \"${input:getClipboard}/${input:promptFolderName}\"",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": true
    },
    "problemMatcher": []
}
],
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "promptFolderName",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.promptStringRemember",
      "args": {
        "key": "FolderName",
        "description": "Enter the folder name:"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "rememberFolderName",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.remember",
      "args": {
        "key": "FolderName"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "getClipboard",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.getClipboard"
    }
]
```

The task uses the possibility to remember what you have entered, no need to type Enter to confirm the previous text.

VSC has a task/launch variable `${CLIPBOARD}` but it returns an empty string in my version of VSC. So I added a command to get the clipboard content.

---

In the File Explorer Right-Click on the folder and select the option **Copy Path**.

Now start your task: **Create_Folder_and_Markdown_File**